# Eclipse - Can not create a web application project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have installed a new version of Eclipse Kepler and have installed the Google Plugin from "http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3" using "Help/Install new software". However, the "g" button to allow the creation of a web application is not in the menu bar. Also when I go to "File>New" the option "Web Application Project" does not appear (I have checked under "Other". What else do I need to install please?

I have used this reference "http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html#installing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by installing Eclipse-JEE. It recognised the Eclipse I had already installed, and spent a lot of time on configuring, and configured its self for me. I was very re-leaved as I expected to spend hours re-doing all the work. So if you have a similar issue do not hesitate to install Eclipse-JEE (do not remove the old Eclipse first).

Regards,

Glyn

Answer (score 0):

You need the [GWT SDK](http://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html) as well, but that is usually installed with the plugin. Unless you deselected *SDK* during the installation. What do you see when you go to *Window>Preference>Google>Web Toolkit*? Any entries there? If not you can use the *Add...* button to install SDKs.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thank you very much for your reply and I apologise for waisting your time. I have resolved this as per below. Regards, Glyn.